# How to give single back slash to a variable in c# program?

Tags: c#, escaping

I want to assign a single backslash to a variable. I tried both single (`\`) slash and double (`\\`) slashes and checked. Can any one help me?

Comment: Aside from this being a duplicate, in future please show what you've tried as code rather than describing it, and tell us the results as well, compared with what you were expecting.

Comment: string sqlservername=textBox2.Text;                                                                                                         string sqldatabasename=textBox2.Text;                                                                                           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source="+sqlservername+";Initial Catalog="+sqldatabasename+";Integrated Security=True");                     When sqlservername =ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS,while running application the servername will change into ADMIN\\SQLEXPRESS which can be seen in debug mode

Comment: So i thought that the server name can be made by adding two strings which can be seperated by a single back slash.thats why i asked !

Comment: All of this should be *edited into the question* rather than put as comments. But basically, the problem is that you're looking at the debugger representation of the string, which escapes backslashes. If you see `\\` in the debugger, there's only actually a single backslash in the string. Log it and you'll see that.